# jSerialComm - SerialPortEvent.getReceivedData() returns null when Arduino Message is received

Tags: java, arduino

I'm making a program in Java which processes weather data recived from an Arduino Uno. It stores the data in a database and sends it to different apis.

I'm uses the [jSerialComm library](https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/) to get the data, which is sent via Serial Port from the Arduino. I'm using the `SerialPortEvent`, which is fired as soon as the Arduino sends any data (I'm not using `InputStream`, because of some other things in the programm won't work anymore).

#### Javacode:

(enable() is called in the main method of the program)

```java
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortDataListener;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortEvent;

public class Arduino implements SerialPortDataListener {

    @Override
    public void enable() {
        SerialPort comPort = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM5");
        System.out.println(comPort.getDescriptivePortName());
        comPort.openPort();
        comPort.setBaudRate(9600);
        comPort.addDataListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int getListeningEvents() {
        return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        byte[] newData = event.getReceivedData();
        System.out.println(newData);
    }

}
```

#### Arduino programm:

(Just a simple testprogram for now)

```c
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

int i = 0;

void loop() {
  Serial.println(i);
  i++;
  delay(1000);
}
```

But no matter what I'm doing, the `SerialPortEvent.getReceivedData()` methode always returns `null`, instead of the `byte[]`-Object (Its printed out once a second, as the Arduino sends its data):

#### Console Output:

```
User-Specified Port
null
null
null 
null
...
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

After messing around with your code a bit I've gotten it to work. First, you need to set the event to only trigger when data has been read by updating the getListeningEvents method to the following:

```
@Override
public int getListeningEvents() {
    return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_RECEIVED;
}
```

Then, you need to interpret the array of bytes that is returned as a string by changing the serialEvent method to this:

```
@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    byte[] newData = event.getReceivedData();
    System.out.print(new String(newData));
}
```

This will print the numbers with newlines, because the Arduino is already sending newline characters after every number.

Comment: Well done @Kwonunn with the answer. It is full of details, it contains code example and gives also explanation of the solution proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get `SerialPortEvent` type inside `serialEvent` method then read the data as stream in case event triggers that data is ready, by first declaring input stream that should be accessible to the method :

```
InputStream inputStream = comPort.getInputStream();
```

Then `serialEvent` should be like this:

```
@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
switch(event.getEventType())
{
  case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
     System.out.println("empty");
     break;
  case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE: 
     try
     {
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        while(inputStream.available() > 0)
        {
           int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
        }
        totalReadBuffer = readBuffer;
        System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
     }
     catch(IOException e)
     {
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }
     break;
  }
}
}
```

You can check [Link](https://github.com/rtatol/serial-event-listener-arduino/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/arduino/listener/SerialPortListener.java) for full code, please note that class used for serial communication is `SerialPortEventListener` you can try it instead